# How do I save the XML output of this php script to its own file?

Tags: php, xml

Hi there I have this PHP script that generates an XML sitemap file. Google does not allow sitemaps to have more than 50,000 records (i.e. URLs) - however I have over a million. I was thinking of putting in a loop but need to figure out how I save the XML output generated by this script to its own sitemap xml file eg. sitemap0_to_50000.xml

Thanks! Any help for this rookie PHP coder would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<?php
      $databaseServer = "localhost";
      $databaseUsername = "username";
      $databasePassword = "password";
      $databaseName = "database";
      $databaseTable = "tablename";
      header("Content-Type: text/xml");
      function xmlentities($text)
      {
        $search = array('&','<','>','"','\'');
        $replace = array('&amp;','&lt;','&gt;','&quot;','&apos;');
        return str_replace($search,$replace,$text);   
      }
      print chr(60)."?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?".chr(62);
      print chr(60)."urlset xmlns='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd'".chr(62);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$databaseTable."`";
      $link = @mysql_connect($databaseServer,$databaseUsername,$databasePassword);
      @mysql_select_db($databaseName,$link);
      $result = mysql_unbuffered_query($sql,$link);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
      {
        // create the loc (URL) value based on the $row array, for example:
        $loc = $row["url"];
        print "<url>";
        print "<loc>".xmlentities($loc)."</loc>";
        print "</url>";
      }
      print "</urlset>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing it onto a page you could directly write it to an Xml file in PHP

or also you can use the **saveXML()** function in php to save your complete DOM tree into a file

you can find the complete documentation here

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

Hope it helps !